# Jetpack Compose - TextField not updating focused/unfocused SupportingText colours

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Came across a strange thing yesterday. When i pass color values to the `focusedSupportingTextColor`/`unfocusedSupportingTextColor` fields of `TextFieldDefaults.color()`, the text colour does not update. Below is my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CounterTextInput(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    hint: String,
    counterText: String,
    maxCount: Int,
    presetText: String = "",
    onValueChange: ((String) -> Unit)? = null,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None
) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(presetText) }
    var currentCount by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    TextField(
        modifier = modifier,
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            if (newText.length <= maxCount) {
                value = newText
                currentCount = newText.length
                onValueChange?.invoke(newText)
            }
        },
        label = {
            RegularText(
                text = hint,
                color = Blue600,
                textSize = 12.sp
            )
        },
        supportingText = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                RegularText(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    text = counterText,
                    textSize = 14.sp,
                )
                RegularText(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    text = "$currentCount/$maxCount",
                    textSize = 12.sp
                )
            }
        },
        maxLines = 1,
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            color = Blue600,
            fontFamily = RegularTextFontFamily,
            fontSize = 12.sp
        ),
        enabled = enabled,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
            focusedContainerColor = White000,
            unfocusedContainerColor = White000,
            disabledContainerColor = Grey100,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Blue600,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey100,
            focusedSupportingTextColor = Blue600,
            unfocusedSupportingTextColor = Grey400,
            cursorColor = Blue600,
            errorTextColor = Red200
        )
    )
}
```

`RegularText` is simply a composable that applies the correct font and styling to a standard `Text` composable. Due to how the theming was applying colours compared to what the design needs, I am somewhat forced to set them manually using the `TextFieldDefaults.color()`. Am I missing something? do i need to hook into the focus state of the composable and then set the colours of the two suppportingText composables from there instead of relying on the convenience fields?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried binding it to a focusRequester with `Modifier.focusRequester(remember { FocusRequester() })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Composable
fun CounterTextInput(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    hint: String,
    counterText: String,
    maxCount: Int,
    presetText: String = "",
    onValueChange: ((String) -> Unit)? = null,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None
) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(presetText) }
    var currentCount by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val isFocused = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    TextField(
        modifier = modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester).onFocusChanged { focusState ->
            isFocused.value = focusState.isFocused
        },
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            if (newText.length <= maxCount) {
                value = newText
                currentCount = newText.length
                onValueChange?.invoke(newText)
            }
        },
        label = {
            RegularText(
                text = hint,
                color = Blue600,
                textSize = 12.sp
            )
        },
        supportingText = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                RegularText(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    text = counterText,
                    textSize = 14.sp,
                )
                RegularText(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    text = "$currentCount/$maxCount",
                    textSize = 12.sp,
                    color = if (isFocused.value) Blue600 else Grey400 // Dynamically set color based on focus
                )
            }
        },
        maxLines = 1,
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            color = Blue600,
            fontFamily = RegularTextFontFamily,
            fontSize = 12.sp
        ),
        enabled = enabled,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            focusedContainerColor = White000,
            unfocusedContainerColor = White000,
            disabledContainerColor = Grey100,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Blue600,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey100,
            cursorColor = Blue600,
            errorIndicatorColor = Red200
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: If you can, try to add some written detail to your answers. Code is helpful, but what bit of the code was the solution? What was the core problem? What strategy did you use? etc.